# How to resolve "tablename to be joined in a table"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I stumbled over a database design in which a table has in one column the name of the table that needs to be joined and in another column the foreign key to that table (integer, not the foreign key name).

I wonder how would you solve this?

This is the current situation:

*Table chatting:*

```
id   |   someColumn   |   chatter_id   |   chatter_ref
--------------------------------------------------------
1        2                1                customers
2        3                1                colleagues
3        4                2                customers
```

*Table customers:*

```
id   |   colA
-------------
1        whatever
2        hello_world
```

*Table colleagues:*

```
id   |   colB
-------------
1        yesyes
```

EDIT:

What I'd do, would be to have multiple `chatting` tables, one for each referenced table.

Like this:

*Table chatting_customers (with a foreign key to customers table):*

```
id   |   someColumn   |   chatter_id
------------------------------------
1        2                1         
3        4                2
```

*Table chatting_colleagues (with a foreign key to colleagues table):*

```
id   |   someColumn   |   chatter_id 
------------------------------------
2        3                1
```

Instead of joining all tables and deciding from which table to select based on the column chatter_ref (with a `select case when chatter_ref = 'customers' then customers.colA else colleagues.colB end from ...`) I would `union` multiple queries. Is this the way to go? Is there a better way to **normalize** this?

Comment: well, your question is not clear. Frame it in other words

Comment: I think there is no other opportunity but to join all the possible tables and decide in your `SELECT` statement which data to select e.g. with a `CASE WHEN chatter_ref = 'customers' THEN...` AND so on.

Comment: @avisheks I edited my question. Please have a look, if it's more clear now.

Comment: @schlonzo Thanks for your contribution, it lead me to another way, which I edited into my question. What do you think about it?

Comment: Why are you creating two tables? Why not just use one and distinct the users by a `user_type` which contains the value *collegues* or *customers*

Comment: `colA` and `colB` should indicate, that in those tables there might be different columns. Putting them all in one table is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic Polymorphic Association anti-pattern. There are a number of possible solutions:

1 Exclusive Arcs (as suggested by Argeman) e.g. for the chatting table

```
id | someColumn | customerId | colleagueId
------------------------------------------
1    2            1
2    3                         1
3    4            2
```

Where both customerId and colleagueID are nullable and exactly one must be not null. Foreign keys can be declared on the customerId and colleagueId.

2 Reverse the Relationship e.g remove the chatterId and chatterRef from the chatting table and create two new tables

customer chattings

```
chattingId | customerId
-----------------------
1            1
3            2
```

colleague chattings

```
chattingId | colleagueId
------------------------
2            1
```

Foreign keys can be declared on the customerId and colleagueId.

3 Create a super-type table for customers/colleagues such as persons and have the chatting table reference the primary key of this new table.

Answer (score 1):

I would put two or more **nullable** rows into the chatting table that are referencing the different other tables.

For example one column chatter_colleague and one chatter_customer. That is also not very nice but I just don't know any *really* good solution!

That would need some effort to keep the table clean but otherwise offers optimal joining and indexing capabilities as far as i know. And it is quite simple, which is desirable in my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the rows of your reference tables into one "table" and include the name of the source table (as a literal value) so you can distinguish them from each other, then join your main table to that, joining on both the id and the source name:

```
select
    c.id,
    c.someColumn,
    d.data
from chatting c
left join (
    select 'customers' type, id, colA data from customers
    union all
    select 'colleagues', id, colB from colleagues) d
  on d.type = c.chatter_ref
  and d.id = c.chatter_id
```

Comment: Okay, that's also a nice way to query this, but is there no way to avoid all this with a better database design? That's what I'm actually looking for. Sorry, if my question is confusing.